# Aid in making a clock code more modular

Tags: c, windows

Can someone help in making this clock code more modular so I will be able to use it in other bigger projects for example: turn into a c function. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
COORD coord = {0, 0};
void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
void showClock(int x_1, int x_2, int x_3,int y){
    long i = 0;                      
    clock_t now = 0;                 int interval = 1;                
    int elapsed = 0;
    int min=0,MIN=0,hrs=0,sec=0;
    int d=0,f=0;
    now = clock();
    for(i = 0L ;  ; i++){
        elapsed = (clock()-now)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if(elapsed>=interval){
            interval += 1;
            if(elapsed%60==0){
                min=elapsed/60;
                d=60*min;
                if(min%60==0){
                    hrs=min/60;
                    f=60*hrs;
                }
            }
            sec=elapsed-d;
            MIN=min-f;
            if(hrs<10){
                gotoxy(x_1,y);printf("0%d",hrs);
            }else{
                gotoxy(x_1,y);printf(":%d",hrs);
            }
            if(min<10){
                gotoxy(x_2,y);printf(":0%d",MIN);
            }else{
                gotoxy(x_2,y);printf(":%2d",MIN);
            }
            if(sec<10){
                gotoxy(x_3,y);printf(":0%d",sec);
            }else{
                gotoxy(x_3,y);printf(":%2d",sec);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    showClock(2,4,7,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

General comments

You should read the manual pages on `time()`, which gives you the time in seconds since 1970, library functions such as `localtime`, `strftime` and `ctime` that can be used to present time values and the `sleep()` function, which sleeps the process for a specified
  number of seconds.

Also:

- variables and structure fields are normally not all-uppercase (X,Y,MIN)
- put a single definition or expression on each line
- leave a blank line between functions.
- `printf` has many formatting options.  Of relevance here is the "%02d"
  format string which prints an integer in 2 places, zero-padded if necessary

  So for 1, it prints '01' and for 10 it prints '10'.
- I prefer to see a space after `while` and `if` etc. and spaces around
  operators (`!=`, `%`, `/` etc)
- make all functions `static` where possible (in this program, all except
  `main`)

---

- your function `delay` is not a good way of delaying, as it ties up the processor.  Better use `sleep`

### Function `showClock`

- I presume you wanted to call `delay`, but you didn't.  This function loops
  continually using 100% of CPU time.  Better would be to use `sleep()` which
  lets other processes run. So sleep(1) would sleep for 1 second.
- using `time()` would be better than `clock()`, as you want intervals in
  seconds
- the single printf format "%02d:%02d:%02d" does what you want without pasing
  three x-coordinates to the function
- most of the rest is unnecessary if you use `sleep` and `time` and the other library functions to present the time interval

Comment: Note that sleep is not ideal for more precise timing, because the thread may sleep *longer* than your delay.  If you want something to happen after a specific amount of time, you usually need OS-specific code (e.g., [Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx) in Windows).